# Concatenated cells return random number instead of date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date, concatenation

I have a question about an excel formula.
I have a some fields I want to concatenate together. One of those is a date made with the formula TODAY. 
When I concatenate all together it will give me a strange number in the place of the data from TODAY formula.

[image: here the screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot the second raw contains data and the formulas used (without =) while the third raw contains the final url. The ad set value contains TODAY formula and it is formatted as date cell, but in the final url it takes it like a random number 42978. How can I fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Pretty sure you've pasted the wrong screenshot.

Comment: A side note: the "random number" is not so random - in fact the number of days after 1/1/1900.

Comment: you may "accept" the answers that solves your concern/issues by clicking on the 'tick' at the answer post.. This will provide fair credit to the author. (and motivate others to ans better too..)  ( :

Answer (score 5):

Instead of concatenating "J13" (or whichever cell contains your date) in the final formula, concatenate TEXT(J13, "yyyy/m/d").

So your formula would become (spaces added for readability)

```
(...) & I13 & TEXT(J13, "yyyy/m/d") & K13 & L13
```

Of course, you can change the format "yyyy/m/d" if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates internally as numbers. Format the cell that shows 42978 with a date format and you will see that it is 31st August 2017.

Edit 1: If the number does not change when it is formatted, then it is not a number, but text.

Edit after the correct screenshot was posted: since the date is not the only piece of data in the cell, formatting won't help, of course, as the whole cell is text.

Excel stores dates as numbers, so you need to convert the number into the text you want to see. Instead of just referencing cell J13, transform the value in J13 to text with

```
Text(J13,"yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Comment: Sorry, I added it. I actually already formatted that cell as date but it didn't change.

Comment: What exactly does that screenshot show? I can't connect the screenshot with anything you've written in the question.

Comment: What formula do you use that creates that number?

Comment: The formula is on the second raw last cell on the right

Comment: @teylyn the last column in each <strike>raw</strike>row has the concatenated data, comprising the content of all the previous columns. 
Included in row 3 is the text '42978' which OP wants as a date.  formula looks like a straight *=a1&a2&a3*.  I don't understand the d/ving but it wasn't me.